# Transition right to left and back using CATransition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an uitabbarcontroller which consists of five uiviewcontrollers.

When i tap a button in the view of the first uiviewcontroller i want the uiviewcontroller to hide and a new uiviewcontroller to be added with a transition from right to left. I have achieved this but when i tap on a button on the new view the app crashes!!! There is no code attached to the button. I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to overcome this problem with the new view?

When i try a modalview transition the view functions properly. This happens when i try to use CATransition. I need CATransition because modalview transitions do not have a transition from right to left or left to right!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code that needed to make the transition between an Uiview of a tabviewcontroller and a new uiview. The code goes to a button's IBAction which exists in one of the uiviews of the tabviewcontroller.

//initialize the app delegate

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// get the view that's currently showing

UIView *currentView = self.view;

// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view view

UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

```
// remove the current view and replace with mynewView1
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
```

//assign the new view to the viewcontroller1. It is the first uiviewcontroller of the uitabbarcontroller. My uitabbarcontroller consists of five uiviewcontrollers in my project.
The button exists in the first viewcontroller1 this is why i am assigning the new view to the viewcontroller1. If the button was pressed from the secondviewcontroller (viewcontroller2) of my uitabbarcontroller i will assign the new view to the secondviewcontroller (viewcontroller2) and so on...

```
appDelegate.viewController1=[[MyMessages alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMessages" bundle:nil];
```

//add it to the window

```
[theWindow addSubview:appDelegate.viewController1.view];

// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Thanks for you help! I have been trying this for more than a day to achieve it. I hope it will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're probably not retaining the new view controller properly. 
But is there a reason you don't use an UINavigatonController and pushViewController/popViewController ? That would make things much easier

Comment: Check my asnwer below i can not post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem with releasing the "new view", which by that You mean the view controller, not controler's view.

I guess You're trying something like this(or just for example):

```
UIViewController *newVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init...];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animId" context:nil];
[UIVIew transitionFromView:old.view toView:newVC.view duration:0.3f options:nil completion:nil];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[newVC release]
```

You release the new view controller (inserting subview doesn't increment the retainCount), so when You perform action (tap button), the target(newVC) is already released and this creates this error.

So, all You have to do is create reference to this view controller(f.e. assign it to some retained property). When You do this modally, view controller presenting the modal automatically keeps the reference in self.modalViewController.